# Intellij shortcut seeking, going over a list

Tags: intellij-idea

Lets say I do find usages, (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) I get a result list, how can I iterate it with my keyboard  I want a keyboard navigation option over a list like in Visual studios F7 F8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the tooltips for "Previous Occurrence" and "Next Occurrence" buttons in the find results view. The default shortcuts for these actions are Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down.